# Is there any difference in mixing and oscillation of neutral mesons?

Tags: particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, mesons

I have often read about neutral Kaon oscillation or neutral B meson mixing. Both are described by the similar box diagrams. So I want to know if we can say neutral kaon mixing and D meson oscillation.

Comment: I don't recall hearing the term applied to meson systems (as opposed to neutrino systems), and I would guess this is related to the short lifetimes of the strongly interacting states that exhibit mixing.

Comment: Mixing an oscillation in neutral mesons (and neutrinos) are more-or-less interchangeable. You certainly can't have one without the other. Mixing more describes the non-alignment of eigenstates in different bases (e.g. mass & weak) whereas oscillation describes the proper-time-dependent probability of each eigenstate